# How to create a GtkImage from a Cairo context?

Tags: gtk, cairo

I got a paint function that works using a Cairo context and the end result should be a GtkImage (without intermediate image creation). I tried to use the gdk_cairo_create function but this code:

```
...
GdkPixbuf *pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new (GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB, FALSE, 8, 22, 22);
GtkWidget *image = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf (pixbuf);
GdkDrawable *drawable = image->window;
cairo_t *ctx = gdk_cairo_create (drawable);
my_cairo_paint_function (ctx);
...
```

fails with:

> Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_cairo_create: assertion `GDK_IS_DRAWABLE (drawable)' failed

Same with a simple:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <cairo.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  cairo_t *ctx = gdk_cairo_create (gtk_widget_get_window (gtk_image_new_from_file ("foobar.png")));
  gtk_main();
  return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why this fails. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`GtkImage` doesn't have a `GdkWindow`, so the call to `gtk_widget_get_window()` or the access of `widget->window` returns `NULL`. You can put the `GtkImage` in a `GtkEventBox` and draw on the event box's `GdkWindow`.

Although, it looks like you're trying (with `gdk_pixbuf_new`) to create an empty space to draw on. In that case, `GtkImage` is not the widget you want -- use `GtkDrawingArea`. And don't forget to call your paint function in the handler for the `event-expose` signal!

Comment: Thanks! I just found out the hard way that it's not enough to just google around for existing code to make Gtk apps work. Will try to get some basic knowledge first, using the official [programming manual](http://developer.gnome.org/doc/GGAD/ggad.html).

Comment: That manual is really old. As you can see from the front page of http://developer.gnome.org, they are working on a new developer site. There are supposed to be new programming examples programmed by competent people in this repository: http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-devel-docs/tree/demos/C These are going to go on the new site, but I haven't really looked at them yet so I can't say how far along they are.